# Cursor in a procedure and calling the procedure

Tags: oracle, if-statement, stored-procedures, plsql, cursor

Need help understanding how to use a cursor variable in a procedure. And use the anonymous block to call the procedure 6 times to run a set of queries. Trying to figure this out have been giving me a headache, thank you in advance for any help.

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE City_Jail_SP
     (lv_query IN NUMBER,
      lv_out out VARCHAR2)
     AS
     cursor qry_lvl IS
BEGIN
   OPEN qry_lvl;
   LOOP
   FETCH INTO
    IF chioce = 1 THEN SELECT AVG(COUNT(*))
    FROM crime_officers
    GROUP BY officer_id;
    
    ELSIF chioce = 2 THEN SELECT MIN(Fine_amount)
    FROM Crime_charges;  
    
    ELSIF chioce = 3 THEN COLUMN (hearing_date-date_charged) HEADING DAYS
    SELECT crime_id, Classification, date_charged, hearing_date,
    ( hearing_date-date_charged)
    FROM crimes
    WHERE hearing_date-date_charged >14;
    
    ELSIF choice = 4 THEN select cl.criminal_id, cl.last, cl.first, cc.Crime_code, cc.Fine_amount
    FROM criminals cl
    JOIN crimes cr
    ON cr.criminal_id = cl.criminal_id
    JOIN crime_charges cc
    ON cc.crime_id = cr.crime_id;
   
    ELSIF chioce = 5 THEN SELECT LAST, FIRST
    FROM officers JOIN crime_officers USING (officer_id)
    JOIN crimes USING (crime_id)
    GROUP BY (LAST, FIRST)
    HAVING COUNT(crime_id)>(SELECT AVG(COUNT(crime_id))
    FROM crimes JOIN crime_officers using (crime_id)
    GROUP BY officer_id);
    
    ELSIF choice = 6 THEN SELECT DISTINCT FIRST, LAST
    FROM criminals JOIN crimes USING (criminal_id)
    JOIN crime_charges USING (crime_id)
    GROUP BY (FIRST, LAST)
    HAVING COUNT(Criminal_ID)<(SELECT AVG(COUNT(Criminal_ID))
    FROM crimes JOIN criminals USING (Criminal_ID)
    GROUP BY Criminal_ID)
    ORDER BY FIRST, LAST;
END IF;
close qry_lvl;
END;    
/
```

Comment: `SELECT AVG(COUNT(*)) GROUP BY officer_id;` You appear to be missing a `FROM` clause in the SQL statement ... Have you tried running the SQL statements outside of PL/SQL  to check whether they work?

Comment: I forgot to add the FROM part in the procedure, but they work when I run the queries individually . @MT0

Comment: `FETCH INTO IF` isn't a valid construction. Also there seem to be multiple `select` statements with no corresponding `into` clause. What is the requirement for this procedure?

Answer (score 0):

It looks as if code you wrote should be shift-deleted so that you could start over.

- you started to declare a cursor, but never finished it
- you didn't declare any cursor variable to store cursor's values into it

  - anyway, you'd rather switch to a cursor FOR loop as it is simpler to use
- you're fetching into ... what?
- there's no `end loop`
- you declared `IN` and `OUT` parameters, but never used any of them
- there's bunch of `select` statements in `IF`, almost all of them returning different data set. Also, there's no `into` clause in any of them. PL/SQL requires it, so you'll have to declare quite a few local variables
- typos, typos, typos ... is it `chioce` or `choice`?
- what is that `column ... heading days` thing supposed to do? Sounds like something related to SQL*Plus

---

Maybe you'd actually want to use refcursors. Here's a simple example based on Scott's schema. Depending on department number, I'm returning different data set.

Sample data:

```
SQL> SELECT * FROM dept;

    DEPTNO DNAME          LOC
---------- -------------- -------------
        10 ACCOUNTING     NEW YORK
        20 RESEARCH       DALLAS
        30 SALES          CHICAGO
        40 OPERATIONS     BOSTON
```

Procedure (kind of simulates what you tried to do):

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE p_test (par_deptno  IN     NUMBER,
  2                                      par_rc         OUT SYS_REFCURSOR)
  3  IS
  4     l_dname  dept.dname%TYPE;
  5  BEGIN
  6     SELECT dname
  7       INTO l_dname
  8       FROM dept
  9      WHERE deptno = par_deptno;
 10
 11     IF l_dname = 'ACCOUNTING'
 12     THEN
 13        OPEN par_rc FOR SELECT d.dname, e.ename, e.job
 14                          FROM dept d
 15                               JOIN emp e
 16                                  ON     e.deptno = d.deptno
 17                                     AND d.deptno = par_deptno;
 18     ELSIF l_dname = 'SALES'
 19     THEN
 20        OPEN par_rc FOR SELECT e.ename, e.job, e.sal
 21                          FROM emp e
 22                         WHERE e.job = 'SALESMAN';
 23     END IF;
 24  END;
 25  /

Procedure created.
```

Testing:

```
SQL> var l_rc refcursor
SQL> exec p_test(10, :l_rc);

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> print :l_rc

DNAME          ENAME      JOB
-------------- ---------- ---------
ACCOUNTING     CLARK      MANAGER
ACCOUNTING     KING       PRESIDENT
ACCOUNTING     MILLER     CLERK

SQL> exec p_test(30, :l_rc);

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> print :l_rc

ENAME      JOB              SAL
---------- --------- ----------
ALLEN      SALESMAN        1600
WARD       SALESMAN        1250
MARTIN     SALESMAN        1250
TURNER     SALESMAN        1500

SQL>
```

---

Please, read some basic PL/SQL documentation, you can't start coding and making up your own syntax. This is [Oracle 12c PL/SQL Language Reference](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/toc.htm). It will take you some time to read it, but - at least - you'll know what you're doing (I hope so).